# Why can't I send data from c# to Javascript file in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a list of a class created in c# that I have to send its values to a javascript file.
I have created a string in c# and put the values of the list in it:

```
count = 0;
JString = "[";
for(i=0; i<x; i++)
{
    JString += "{Source:" + A[i] + ", Number:" + 3 + ", Target:" + B[i] + "},";
    count++;
}
JString = JString.Remove(JString.Length - 1, 1); //to remove the last ,
JString += "]";
GraphData.Text = "" + "var JString =" + JString + " ;" + "var count =" + count + " ;";
```

GraphData is a label to save the string.

In the JavaScript file, I added:

```
 $("#GraphData").val(); //to get the string sent
```

But it's not working this way.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Is that label visible? Is the Visible property set to true?

Comment: What's the markup look like for `GraphData` when it's rendered on your browser?  I think an `asp:Label` gets rendered as a `<span>`, in which case you'd want to call `$('#GraphData').text()` to get the inner text

Comment: Yes it is. First it wasn't but later I have set it to true but still not working

Comment: Is is infinite loop ? This may be source of your problem. Remove 'count++' and it should work
for(i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    JString += "{Source:" + A[i] + ", Number:" + 3 + ", Target:" + B[i] + "},";
    count++;
}

Comment: EOG's right, you have an infinite loop there. the count variable is being incremented inside the for loop. `i` won't be able to ever catch up.

Comment: You should really have a look at [json.net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) or [DataContractJsonSerialize](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/272335/JSON-Serialization-and-Deserialization-in-ASP-NET) to serialize data to JSON.

Comment: The markup is :var JString=]; count=0; But when i run I put breakpoint in the c# file and the string looks different

Comment: I didn't even notice @EOG catch that you have an infinite loop.  Nice!  You should add that as an answer to get +rep.

Comment: No it is not the case. I wrote for(i=0;i<count;i++) by mistake. count++ is another variable i want to use

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=0; i<count; i++)
{
    JString += "{Source:" + A[i] + ", Number:" + 3 + ", Target:" + B[i] + "},";
    count++;
}
```

This looks like an infinte loop. You're increasing both `i` and count by 1 in every cycle, so `i` will always be less than `count`

Answer (score 0):

After you fix the problem with the infite loop, you need to call `$('#GraphData').text()`; because `Label`  in asp.net is rendered as a `span` element.

Answer (score 0):

I think here GraphData is the server control. to get this element use its ClientID

try this

$("# <%= GraphData.ClientID%> ").val();